# What design should be used for holding file information

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, actionscript, directory

I want to create flex/actionscript directory view for my files with php/mysql. I have some ideas that I want to share:

1)I am thinking of creating table (in mysql) "files" and another table "folders", when user loges in i will require all data from "files" and "folders" where Username = 'something'. But the problem is, I will create a lot of entries inside of tables. For example if I will have 100 users, and each user could create 100 entries (files or folders) it means that i will get 10000 entries inside table.

2)My second idea, and I think more safe way of doing it is creating table "users" where will be set id, username, password, ... , files, folders. In files (text format entry) will be listed information about files, and they will be dividend by "*" symbol like this:

```
id*file name*size(in kbytes)*path*status 
example:
15*test.exe*150*/root/*private
16*test2.exe*200*/root/folder1/*public
17*test3.exe*5600*/root/folder1/subfolder/*private
...
```

This info will be outputed when flex once when user loges in, and actionscript will catch it. But the problem is that when i will edit 1 file info (for example 1 file name "test.exe" to "editedtest.exe") i will load back in mysql all data:

```
15*editedtest.exe*150*/root/*private 
16*test2.exe*200*/root/folder1/*public
17*test3.exe*5600*/root/folder1/subfolder/*private
```

Now here is only 3 file info but there can be more than 1000.

so what do you think, how can I solve my task? Or is it better way of doing it and I just don't know about it? Please write your suggestions and thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the term "filesystem" to represent the file/folders structure for each user.

Do not be afraid of a huge amount of lines in your db, databases are designed to handle this.

Also, i
t provides you many advantages :

- lazy loading :  in you directory tree, you can fetch only the root directories/files for the current user, and when the user wants to go in a subfolder, you can load the content of this subfolder. If you store the whole filesystem structure in a string, you have to load the entire structure even if you do need just one line
- unit updates : with a database, you can update a file/folder without loading the full  filesystem structure
- less code : you won't have to parse the text string to re-create the path, you can store it "as is" in the database
- indexation : if you store one file/folder per row, you can index these to accelerate searches. If you store the entire filesystem structure in it's owner row, you cannot perform searches efficiently.

Comment: Yes I agree that it is better way of doing filesystem, but are you sure that big amount of lines in database will not be a problem? if my web application will become famous, and a lot of poeple will start using it (for example 1000 people) each will create a lot of files/folders. So are you sure that database will correctly and rapidly work with a 1 000 000 lines (looking in future)?

Comment: yes,definitely. the mysql team announces that they have 50-million-records databases : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/features.html (search "Scalability" in the page to find the info). The key points for keeping good perfs are good indexes and a well-structured data model.

Comment: thank you very much for that suggestion. I will do like you said. Thanks again for advice.

Answer (score 0):

How to accomplish:

1. Save in mysql what user has access to what sub directory.
2. Write a PHP script that reads the directory that has been queried by the Flash application. Check if the directory belongs to the user. Return all files of that directory. Show navigation buttons in Flash the same way as the web server shows the buttons in directoy listing pages such as: http://www.css-zibaldone.com/articles/directory/examples/3/3.html (googled for apache directory listing example).
3. This approach will perform 1 directory traversal per request. You can then refine this situation by enabling the traversal to return the current directory and also its direct child directory files. Or you cache the results in some files on the hard disk.

I found a file browser app for AJAX: http://www.ajaxfilebrowser.com/